# I can't register my database! DoctrineServiceProvider is said to never be used more

Tags: php, doctrine, silex

I am new at programming and came across some problems recently. I don't know what am I doing wrong because the code itself seems to be just fine (it should work).
Ok, so, I'm using Silex framework and my main problem is to connect database to my application. According to Silex documentation the registration is ok but I don't know why the application can't see any of my tables.
My DoctrineServiceProvider is said to be never used more even though I'm using it several lines further. I would be really grateful for any help.

Here's my code:

```
//...
use Silex\Provider\DoctrineServiceProvider;
//...
$app->register(
    new Silex\Provider\DoctrineServiceProvider(), array(

        'db.options' => array(
            'driver'    => 'pdo_mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'dbname'    => 'apka',
            'user'      => 'root',
            'password'  => '***',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'driverOptions' => [
                1002 => 'SET NAMES utf8',
            ]
        ),
    ));
```

Comment: Hi Bociek. Are you getting an error message of any kind?

Comment: Not really, I get the message (in my twig template) that my list is empty which is supposed to pop up when there is no table found. In Use section of my main php file there is a message "Silex\Provider\DoctrineServiceProvider is never used more" and on the registration there is "Multiple definition exists for class DoctrineServiceProvider" but on the website itself there is no error message.

Comment: They sound like PHPStorm errors/prompts. In any case, if you are importing `Silex\Provider\DoctrineServiceProvider` via `use`, why aren't you simply instantiating it as `new DoctrineServiceProvider()` on line 5 of your code snippet?

Comment: Not that this should matter if the above code snippet is in the global namespace. I suspect there is more to this than the code you are showing - for instance what about the callback that makes the db query and sends it to the view. Can you include these?

Comment: Excuse me but do you want to see screenshots of the result in browser or the code itself (the mysql query inside the code)?

Comment: i think you need to provide more context to your question - the code you provided already doesn't seem to have any obvious issues so it's possible that you need to show more to give people here a fuller picture of what is happening (and hopefully give you an answer). So, adding more code as you think appropriate should be helpful.